# Xamrin: Why two folders one in AddData folder and SDK folder are used by Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Xamrin needs two folder for compiling application one is  'C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Xamarin' folder and another is
actual android sdk folder.

Can anybody provide clarification on these? Usage is not clear which one is imp.

Which packages should be available under AppData?

Answer (score 0):

- The Android SDK folder is actually that, a folder that is installed and maintained via Google's SDK installers and who's content is **untouched** by Visual Studio/Xamarin tools. Binaries are run from there, SDKs fetched, etc.. but the contents are not changed.
- The `AppData` `Xamarin` subdirectory is used as a cache for multiple things, including downloaded and *inflated* SDK components for the various Android API levels.

Basically, instead of inflating needed SDK components into each and every solution/project directory, Xamarin uses the `AppData` area to cache and share these SDK assets across all your Visual Studio solution and projects.

Windows:

```
%LocalAppData%\Xamarin\Local
%LocalAppData%\Xamarin\Cache
```

OS-X:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xamarin
~/Library/Caches/XamarinStudio-5.0/DerivedData
~/Library/Caches/XamarinStudio-6.0/DerivedData
```